# Vue & <noscript> issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue app deployed and working as expected from functional perspective, however whenever I try to view source of rendered pages in a browser (any browser to be more precise) actual content is not visible and the body section starts with the following:

```
<noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but this site doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
```

When I inspect individual elements in can then see the source code.

The same results when tested with **yarn dev** and **dist** package from **yarn build**.

```
vue --version
2.9.6
```

Vue has been updated with the following:

```
yarn global upgrade @vue/cli
```

Needless to say that this is a major SEO issue.

Is this an app configuration or vue's environment's issue?

Comment: That is the normal behaviour. If you want to deliver the content after the execution of JavaScript, you either have to [prerender the page or use server-side rendering](https://ssr.vuejs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

According to W3schools.com

> The "noscript" tag defines an alternate content to be displayed to
> users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser
> that doesn't support script.
>
> The "noscript" element can be used in both "head" and "body" tag. When
> used inside "head", the "noscript" element could only contain "link",
> "style", and "meta" elements.

So we can easily conclude that, if any browser doesn't support or disabled the javascript then we can write some tags in the <noscript%gt; tag to inform the user that about it. Ex "Sorry your browser either doesn't support javascript or its disabled please enable it.

In the context of Vue, there is  tag inside index.html which looks something as follows:

```
<noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
```

It's just saying that, if you don't see our app working in your browser then maybe your browser doesn't support javascript. As the whole application is written with Vue and Vue is written in javascript.

So either your browser has disabled javascript which may be the underline issue, or your browser doesn't support javascript which is quite unbelievable as all modern browser does support it unless you have an old browser.

Comment: He was trying to "view the source" of rendered pages in a browser. The app is working fine, and this's a normal behavior of Vue with client-side rendering.